# Cómo ordenar una propiedad de un array, dependiendo otra propiedad, en JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array.

```
[
    {
        "id": 659718,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2897397,
        "source": "type",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2728223,
        "source": "okol",
        "confidence_levels": "media_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2291725,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6688,
        "source": "estudio",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 1050922,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6787,
        "source": "crm",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",     
    },
    {
        "id": 6588,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 11334,
        "source": "softec",
        "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla",      
    }
]
```

Básicamente lo que requiero es, primero hacer un sort respecto al nivel de confianza (alta_confianza, media_confianza, baja_confianza, etc...) y, con base en esa propiedad ("confidence_levels"), organizar alfabéticamente la fuente ('source').

Resultado esperado:
Ordenar primero los ids de alta confianza y después las fuentes (source) que están asociadas a ese nivel // avaluos, type, ventana.
Ordenar los ids de baja confianza y sus fuentes asociadas // crm, estudio
... etc.

De momento solo he logrado organizar o la propiedad 'source' o la propiedad 'confidence_levels', pero no una en función de la otra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Actualización

Para ordenar según el nivel de confianza por su prioridad y el "source" en orden alfabético, se puede crear un diccionario de prioridades y usarlo para armar una clave compuesta por [nivel de prioridad + source]

```js
const data = [{"id":659718,"source":"avaluos","confidence_levels":"alta_confianza"},{"id":2897397,"source":"type","confidence_levels":"alta_confianza"},{"id":2728223,"source":"okol","confidence_levels":"media_confianza"},{"id":2291725,"source":"avaluos","confidence_levels":"alta_confianza"},{"id":6688,"source":"estudio","confidence_levels":"baja_confianza"},{"id":1050922,"source":"ventana","confidence_levels":"alta_confianza"},{"id":6787,"source":"crm","confidence_levels":"baja_confianza"},{"id":6588,"source":"ventana","confidence_levels":"alta_confianza"},{"id":11334,"source":"softec","confidence_levels":"nunca_usarla"}]

const levelOrder = {
  "alta_confianza": 1,
  "media_confianza": 2,
  "baja_confianza": 3,
  "nunca_usarla" : 4
}

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => `${levelOrder[a.confidence_levels]}${a.source}`.localeCompare(`${levelOrder[b.confidence_levels]}${b.source}`))

console.log(sorted)
```

##### Respuesta original

Se puede crear una llave concatenando `confidence_level` y `source` y usándola como comparador en la función `sort`:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 659718,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2897397,
        "source": "type",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2728223,
        "source": "okol",
        "confidence_levels": "media_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2291725,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6688,
        "source": "estudio",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 1050922,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6787,
        "source": "crm",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",     
    },
    {
        "id": 6588,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 11334,
        "source": "softec",
        "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla",      
    }
]

const ordered = data.sort((a, b) => (a.confidence_levels + a.source).localeCompare(b.confidence_levels + b.source))
console.log(ordered)
```

Se puede hacer con la función [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) de la biblioteca Lodash

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 659718,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2897397,
        "source": "type",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2728223,
        "source": "okol",
        "confidence_levels": "media_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 2291725,
        "source": "avaluos",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6688,
        "source": "estudio",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 1050922,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 6787,
        "source": "crm",
        "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",     
    },
    {
        "id": 6588,
        "source": "ventana",
        "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
    },
    {
        "id": 11334,
        "source": "softec",
        "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla",      
    }
]

ordered = _.orderBy(data, ['confidence_levels', 'source'], ['asc', 'asc']);

console.log(ordered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola @Lobos 
Muchísimas gracias por las dos opciones de solución, me ayudaron completamente con lo que requería hacer.
:-) Aprendí algo nuevo hoy.

Comment: ¿Cómo `baja_comfianza` puede tener un nivel superior a `media_confianza` en un ordenamiento por nivel de confianza? El OP claramente establece el orden requerido por nivel de confianza y tus 2 propuestas fallan. Curioso que el mismo OP haya aceptado tu respuesta. 

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar un callback pasado a la funcion array.sort() y un poco de lógica dentro para ordenarlos como quieres:

```js
let myarr = [
  {
      "id": 659718,
      "source": "avaluos",
      "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 2897397,
      "source": "type",
      "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 2728223,
      "source": "okol",
      "confidence_levels": "media_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 2291725,
      "source": "avaluos",
      "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 6688,
      "source": "estudio",
      "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 1050922,
      "source": "wentana",
      "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 6787,
      "source": "crm",
      "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza",     
  },
  {
      "id": 6588,
      "source": "ventana",
      "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza",
  },
  {
      "id": 11334,
      "source": "softec",
      "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla",      
  }
]

let confLevels = ['alta_confianza','media_confianza','baja_confianza','nunca_usarla']

myarr.sort((a, b) => {
  if(confLevels.indexOf(a.confidence_levels)>confLevels.indexOf(b.confidence_levels)) return 1;
  if(confLevels.indexOf(a.confidence_levels)<confLevels.indexOf(b.confidence_levels)) return -1; 
  if(a.source.localeCompare(b.source) > 0 ) return 1
  else return -1
})

console.log(myarr)
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento ordenas por `id`? Es parte del requisito funcional en la pregunta. Tu solución no responde la pregunta. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @MauricioContreras Lee bien

Comment: El OP dice que ordene una condición en función de la otra y estoy haciendo justamente eso, la primera es el nivel de confianza de alta a nunca usarla, y después ordenó alfabéticamente el source

Comment: Dice en la pregunta 'ordenar primero los ids de alta confianza' se refiere a los valores alta_confianza-media confianza etc, no a la propiedad 'id' de los objetos

Comment: Ese es el problema con responder preguntas mal formuladas. Todas las respuestas son erróneas.

Comment: Y gracias por el consejo, pero he leído bien, hay un párrafo que habla de ordenar por nivel de confianza y otro párrafo que habla de ordenar por id de alta confianza y luego por fuente: *Resultado esperado: Ordenar primero los ids de alta confianza y después las fuentes (source) que están asociadas a ese nivel // avaluos, type, ventana*.

Comment: No puedes saber lo que quería el OP si la pregunta está mal formulada, entonces los criterios de ordenamiento serían 3 y no 2, si el OP acepto la respuesta de arriba será porque era lo que esperaba, mejor quéjate de la pregunta y no de la respuesta

Comment: @MauricioContreras los ids no se requieren ordenar... simplemente el OP metio esa palabra y no se ha sabido expresar ... y de ser asi no tiene sentido ...

Answer (score 1):

La primera solución (y la aceptada) que ofrece @Lobos solo funciona porque las palabras del ejemplo calzan, pero el método de concatenar las 2 o más propiedades no es seguro en ningún caso:

Ejemplo:

```js
const data = [ { "source": "a", "confidence_levels": "ab", },{ "source": "ba",  "confidence_levels": "a", } ];

const ordered = data.sort((a, b) => (a.confidence_levels + a.source).localeCompare(b.confidence_levels + b.source))
console.log(ordered)
```

Como se aprecia no está bien ordenado, porque la concatenación produce palabras iguales.

Lo que me lleva a responder con lo siguiente:

Para ordenar no podemos valer de las funciones [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) y [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), ambos métodos funcionan en base a una lógica 1,-1 o 0. Estos números son generados en base a comprar 2 elementos

Ahora supongamos que tenemos 2 objetos con 2 propiedades cada uno

```
const obj1 = {prop1: "a", prop2: "x" };
const obj2 = {prop1: "z", prop2: "z" };

let comparacion_1 = obj1.prop1.localeCompare(obj2.prop1); // -1
let comparacion_2 = obj1.prop2.localeCompare(obj2.prop2); // -1
```

Obviamente tenemos 2 valores, pero nosotros queremos 1 solo, para eso generamos este único valor mutilando en por 10 el de mayor prioridad (el primero) y sumándolo con el segundo

```
let comparacion = obj1.prop1.localeCompare(obj2.prop1) *10 + obj1.prop2.localeCompare(obj2.prop2); //-11
```

En base a esta lógica podemos ir agregando propiedades de ordenamiento según necesitemos y multiplicando por potencia de 10, es decir: 1,10,100,1000, etc y obtener de esta manera un número que permita ordenar

Entonces podemos generar un código parecido a:

```js
const data = [{ "source": "avaluos", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza", },
{ "source": "type", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "okol", "confidence_levels": "media_confianza" },
{ "source": "avaluos", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "estudio", "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza" },
{ "source": "ventana", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "crm", "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza" },
{ "source": "ventana", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "softec", "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla" }];


Array.prototype.OrderBy = function (...args) {
    if (args.length == 0) return this.sort();
    const ordOptions  = { numeric: true };
    return this.sort((a, b) =>
        args.reduce((acc, x, i) =>
            acc += Math.pow(10, args.length - i) * a[x].localeCompare(b[x], undefined, ordOptions)
        , 0));
}

console.log(data.OrderBy("confidence_levels","source"));
```

Donde en la función `OrderBy` vamos ingresando los nombres de las propiedades, y cuyo orden de entrada determina su prioridad.

---

Ahora bien, podemos generar algo más versátil complicando las cosas. Para esto ocuparé "encadenación de funciones" que me parece lo adecuado para este caso

```js
const data = [{ "source": "avaluos", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza", },
{ "source": "type", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "okol", "confidence_levels": "media_confianza" },
{ "source": "avaluos", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "estudio", "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza" },
{ "source": "ventana", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "crm", "confidence_levels": "baja_confianza" },
{ "source": "ventana", "confidence_levels": "alta_confianza" },
{ "source": "softec", "confidence_levels": "nunca_usarla" }];

Array.prototype.OrderNow = function () {
    let ords = this[Symbol.for("$_orden")];
    if (!ords) return this;
    const opt ={ numeric: true };
    const factor = a => a === "ASC" ? 1 : -1;
    const getExp = (a,b) => String(a.exp(b));
    return this.sort((a, b) =>
        ords.reduce((acc, x, i) =>
            acc += factor(x.dir) * Math.pow(10, ords.length - i) * getExp(x,a).localeCompare(getExp(x,b),undefined,opt)
         , 0));
}

Array.prototype.AddOrder = function (exp, dir = "ASC") {
    if (dir.toUpperCase() != "DESC") dir = "ASC";
    if (!this[Symbol.for("$_orden")]) this[Symbol.for("$_orden")] = [];
    this[Symbol.for("$_orden")].push({ exp, dir});
    return this;
}


// orden lexicográfico
//console.log(
//    data
//        .AddOrder(a => a.confidence_levels,"asc")
//        .AddOrder(a => a.source, "desc")
//        .OrderNow()
//);

//EDIT:
//orden según prioridad alta_confianza > media_confianza > baja_confianza > etc
console.log(
    data
        .AddOrder(a => {
          if( a.confidence_levels=="alta_confianza") return 2; 
          else if( a.confidence_levels=="media_confianza") return 1; 
          else if( a.confidence_levels=="baja_confianza") return 0; 
          return -1;
        },"desc")
        .AddOrder(a => a.source)
        .OrderNow()
);
```

Creamos 2 funciones

**1.- AddOrder** Que recibe como parámetro una expresión y como segundo parámetro opcional un orden "ASC" o "DESC". Esta función NO ordena solo indicando el "Como ordenar"

**2.- OrderNow** Que genera el ordenamiento en base a la asignación anterior

*Nota: Estos códigos son solo una aproximación, con el propósito de dar a entender las posibilidades que existen. Seguramente requieren algo de depuración para ser puestos en producción*

---

**UPDATE**

He modificado el último código para mostrar cómo la función expuesta es capaz de realizar un ordenamiento bajo un criterio de prioridades.

Comment: `sort` y `localeCompare` no funcionan apegados a `-1`, `0` y `1`. Eso puede ser una convención, pero funcionan apegados a `negativo`, `cero` y `positivo`. Por lo cual, cuando se usa una función de comparación para `sort`, con elementos numéricos, basta devolver la diferencia entre los elementos para que el ordenamiento funcione. En todo caso, si los elementos a ordenar no son numéricos, se adopta la convención de devolver `-1`, `0` o `1`, dependiendo si un elemento se considera menor, igual o mayor que el otro. Puedes devolver cualquier otro valor negativo, o positivo según sea el caso.

Comment: Por cierto, mismo comentario que dejé en la respuesta de Lobos. Tu solución no ordena adecuadamente por nivel de confianza. ¿Cómo `baja_comfianza` es un nivel de confianza superior a `media_confianza`? El OP deja claro en su pregunta, que primero se ordene por nivel de confianza, y establece el orden de las mismas. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @MauricioContreras La especificación como bien indicas señala que se entrega un `positivo`, `negativo` y `cero` (no habla de números), en javascript no existe ningún elemento u objeto que represente el negativo y/o positivo por sí solo, además señala que el valor devuelto no debe presentar ningún orden relativo entre la comparación. Por estas razones los navegadores resuelven entregar -1,1 y 0, cual es un estándar de facto

Comment: Sobre el otro tema, yo asumí que el orden era lexicográfico porque la respuesta de @Lobos fue aceptada. No obstante la solución final que propuse es una función genérica de ordenamiento, por lo que para ordenar como tu estas diciendo solo hay que entregar los argumentos necesarios a la función como:  `.AddOrder(a => a.confidence_levels=="alta_confianza" ? "0" :  (a.confidence_levels=="media_confianza"?"1":"2"))`